# Force Pandas to Read in Column as raw unicode

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, date, unicode

I need to account for folks entering data into a spreadsheet completely wrong. I cannot control their behavior because I'm scraping it from another website. However, there is some truly bad data entry, such as the following for "Tons" of cargo:

[image]

Lovely, right? I need to figure out a way to read numbers like that into pandas without pandas auto-casting them to dates, after which point it's impossible to convert them back to 11955 and 11862. To add a cherry on top, the following won't work:

```
dfx = pd.read_excel(ii,header=None,dtype={'Tons': str})
```

because often the data has no column headers and I'm inferring the header from the order of the data, which thankfully doesn't change. So how to get pandas to be agreeable here?

Once I read in the data, even if I then change the entire column to unicode or string, it'll just be a unicode or string representation of the date:

```
 2055-01-19 00:00:00
 2062-01-18 00:00:00
```

So I need to read it in either "raw" (not sure what that means) as `1,19,55` without pandas trying to guess at the type, or just somehow as a number ignoring the commas...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `converter` for the column `Tons` to format the data as you want as `pd.read_execel` [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas.read_excel) explains:

> **converters** : dict, default None Dict of functions for converting
>   values in certain columns. Keys can either be integers or column
>   labels, values are functions that take one input argument, the Excel
>   cell content, and return the transformed content.

for example you can use the following converter

```
tons_converter = lambda x: int("".join(x.split(',')))
dfx = pd.read_excel(ii,header=None,dtype={0: str}, converters={0: tons_converter})
```

### reproducible example

Here's an example creating a csv file on the fly and applying the conversion.

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd 

data = """
1,125,125
10,578,589
12
"""

tons_converter = lambda x: int("".join(x.split(',')))
dfx = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data),header=None,dtype=object, sep="|", converters={0: tons_converter})

print(dfx.head())
```

The ouput is you want:

```
          0
0   1125125
1  10578589
2        12
```

Comment: Will try this when I have a chance, but that seems like it should work, thanks, will give you answer when confirmed